# Difficulty finding the root of this polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, roots, curvature

My problem is somewhat long but I hope someone can shed some light on this.

Full disclosure - I have posted in different forums (NOT StackExchange) to seek help but no fruitful answers so far.

Here it is:

Take the following equation:

$y(x) = \frac{b(1-x)}{b(1-x)+(1-a)x}$

The curvature K of the above polynomial is a function of the first and second order derivative of y(x) as follows:

$=\frac {|y''|}{\left(1+{y'}^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$

Now, I am interested in the maximum curvature of this polynomial, so we need to differentiate *k* with respect to x and find its roots:

$k'=\frac{d}{dx}k$

Hence, I am interested in finding the roots of *k'* as a function of a and b, particularly for values of x between 0 and 1. I know a solution exists because graphically it is evident as can be observed below:

[image]

That said, obtaining an general algebraic solution as a function of a and b (parameters that can be adjusted but that will always be between 0 and 1) has been a challenge!

Any input you may have would be GREATLY appreciated!

Many thanks in advance!

J

Comment: What was your choice of $a$ and $b$ in the plot?

Comment: In fact - that's irrelevant - for all values of a and b are between 0 and 1 and all of them cross the x-axis

Answer (score 1):

By introducing $c=\frac{1-a}{b}-1$ you can simplify your function to

$$y(x)=\frac{1-x}{1+cx}.$$

We find the maximum of $k$ by finding the maximum of $k^2$. We arrive to the function

$$\left(2c\left(1+c\right)\right)^{2}\frac{\left(1+cx\right)^{6}}{\left(\left(1+cx\right)^{4}+\left(1+c\right)^{2}\right)^{3}}.$$

We can forget the constant factor, take the cube root (it's always positive so maxed when cube root is maxed) and make the change of variable $t=(1+cx)^2$. This leads to maximizing the function

$$g(t)= \frac{t}{t^2+(1+c)^2}$$

and we find its maximum at $t=\pm (1+c) = \left|\frac{1-a}{b}\right|$. Winding everything back, we have that the curvature is maximized at

$$x_{\max} = \frac{\sqrt{\pm(1+c)}-1}{c} = \frac{\sqrt{\left|\frac{1-a}{b}\right|}-1}{\frac{1-a}{b}-1}.$$

[Tested here.](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/njbzrujfk0)